# Angle of Revolution for a truck

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing a problem out of my textbook, which I don't understand.  In my Alg2/Trig class, we are learning about angular speed, and linear speed in terms of angular speed.  I can't figure out how to solve this using those.  **Please note, a full explanation is not required.  Even just a hint can help.  Lastly, I appreciate any help, but helping me using math that is way beyond me doesn't help me.**

Problem:

> A tite on a truck has a diameter of `31.125` in.  Through what angle (radians) does the tire turn when traveling 1 mile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, in general, the angle $\theta$ turned by the wheel $$\theta=2\pi \times \frac{\text{distance traveled by the wheel}\ (D)}{\text{circumference of wheel}\ (\pi d)}=\frac{2 D}d$$
setting the corresponding values of distance, $D=1\ \mathrm{mile}=1609.344\ m$ & diameter, $d=31.125\ in.=31.125\times 0.0254\ m$, the angle turned by the wheel 
$$\theta=\frac{2\times 1609.344\ m}{31.125\times 0.0254\ m}=\color{red}{4071.325302\ \mathrm{radians}}$$

Answer (score 1):

When the wheel does one rotation it will have travelled a distance equal to its circumference. When the wheel does a rotation through $\theta$ radians it will have travelled a distance of $r\theta$ (definition of radian measure). So you want to solve $d=r\theta$.

$$1mi = 31.125in\times\theta$$
$$63360=31.125\theta$$
$$\theta=2035.66\space(2dp)$$

*I'm not American so double check my calculations of your weird units :p